# can you store a python list and or beautiful soup ovject inside a python list

Tags: python, list, syntax, beautifulsoup

I am wondering in python can you;

(1) store a list inside a list

(2) store a beautiful soup (soup) object inside a list?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Anything else?

Comment: For your future adventures with python.  The compiler is a easier to ask than stackoverflow, and it will be the final arbiter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store anything inside a list.